# How to get 2 applications accessing same mdf file with SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have two .NET applications, one running on 2.0 and the other running on 4.5.

The .NET 2.0 application is the main application where the user inputs data and this runs perfectly. The .NET 4.5 application is a Telerik Reporting site that runs a report based on data entered in the 2.0 application and is receiving the error below

> system error 32 (the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another person)

Both applications are using this the connection strings below.

```
<add name="sqlserver" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\FolderName\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I set up SQL Server Express to use windows authentication but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As @Oscar mentions below, it is best you set up the a database server and point the apps to same DB on the SQL Server. As you have indicated in your question that you already have set up SQL Express, refer to this article [Beginners guide to accessing SQL Server through C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C). And there are numerous related resources available online covering this topic. Good Luck!

Comment: @chandan : <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="data source=localhost;database=DBname;uid=sa;pwd=password;" />              use connection string like this .;instead of AttachDbFilename try to specify database name(initial catalog).

Answer (score 5):

You can't. SQL Server process holds a lock on the file while it's up and running. 
But alternatively, you can setup a database server and point both apps to the same database.
Or have two instances with replication. 
Database files are good for development, but not to be used in production environments.

Comment: up-vote, I am sure you are correct! but could you help me find another site saying the same thing.